# insert or ignore multiple documents in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-query

I have a collection in which all of my documents have at least these 2 fields, say `name` and `url` (where `url` is unique so I set up a unique index on it).  Now if I try to insert a document with a duplicate `url`, it will give an error and halt the program.  I don't want this behavior, but I need something like `mysql`'s `insert or ignore`, so that mongoDB should not insert the document with duplicate `url` and continue with the next documents.

Is there some parameter I can pass to the `insert` command to achieve this behavior? I generally do a batch of inserts using `pymongo` as:

```
collection.insert(document_array)
```

Here `collection` is a collection and `document_array` is an array of documents.

So is there some way I can implement the `insert or ignore` functionality for a multiple document insert?

Comment: Are you performing these inserts using an iterator/loop of objects in memory, or using mongo's built-in batchInsert methods?

Comment: @DeaconDesperado i am using `pymongo`'s batch insert method. So i have a loop and in each iteration i perform a batch insert operation to insert multiple documents

Comment: @lovesh Any chance you could accept an answer here?

Answer (score 13):

Set the `continue_on_error` flag when calling [insert()](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert). Note PyMongo driver 2.1 and server version 1.9.1 are required:

> continue_on_error (optional): If True, the database will not stop
>   processing a bulk insert if one fails (e.g. due to duplicate IDs).
>   This makes bulk insert behave similarly to a series of single inserts,
>   except lastError will be set if any insert fails, not just the last
>   one. If multiple errors occur, only the most recent will be reported
>   by error().

Answer (score 13):

Use insert_many(), and set ordered=False.

This will ensure that all write operations are attempted, even if there are errors:
http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_many

Comment: Stil works as of MongoDB 5.0, as well as allowing Mongo to make the writes in the most efficient way when order is unimportant but also using in `try` and `except pymongo.errors.BulkWriteError` will avoid errors displaying to the console.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
try:
    coll.insert(
        doc_or_docs=doc_array,
        continue_on_error=True)
except pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError:
    pass
```

The insert operation will still throw an exception if an error occurs in the insert (such as trying to insert a duplicate value for a unique index), but it will not affect the other items in the array. You can then swallow the error as shown above.

Comment: when i see the code keeping throwing out DuplicateKeyError, i wonder whether this is a bug or what? Now i know it~~Thanks~

Comment: Mind you, it only throws the last error. not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put your call to `.insert()` inside a `try: ... except:` block and continue if the insert fails?

In addition, you could also use a regular `update()` call with the `upsert` flag. Details here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-update%28%29

Comment: If he/she is using the batch insert (passing an array of documents to the insert method) the first one that fails will trigger the exception and then break out of the insertion.  The only way I can think to get the insert to fail silently and then continue with the remaining documents is to iterate through them in the script.

Comment: Doesnt mongoDB support something like `insert or ignore` in mysql or sqlite where anything which is a duplicate will silently be ignored and continue with the rest

Answer (score 0):

If you have your array of documents already in memory in your python script, why not insert them by iterating through them, and simply catch the ones that fail on insertion due to the unique index?

```
for doc in docs:
  try:
    collection.insert(doc)
  except pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError:
    print 'Duplicate url %s' % doc
```

Where collection is an instance of a collection created from your connection/database instances and docs is the array of dictionaries (documents) you would currently be passing to insert.

You could also decide what to do with the duplicate keys that violate your unique index within the `except` block.

Comment: i wanted to do a `batch insert` because a it is faster than inserting one document at a time and i have thousands of documents to insert

Answer (score -1):

It is highly recommended to use `upsert`

```
  stat.update({'location': d['user']['location']}, \
       {'$inc': {'count': 1}},upsert = True, safe = True)
```

Here `stat` is the collection if visitor location is already present in the collection, `count` is increased by one, else `count` is set to `1`.

Here is the link for documentation http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-UpsertswithModifiers

Comment: if i use an upsert i cannot perform a batch insert. I have to go over each documnet,check if there is already some document with that url in the collection and if its not there insert it.

Comment: Mongo DB documents are stored as B tree, bulk insert is driver specific. [http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Inserting#Inserting-Bulkinserts](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Inserting#Inserting-Bulkinserts)

Comment: OP is not asking for upsert. He wants a bulk insert that does not fail when one record fails. That is something completely different.

Answer (score -3):

What I am doing :

1. Generate array of MongoDB ids I want to insert (hash of some values in my case)
2. Remove existing IDs (I am using a Redis queue bcoz performance, but you can query mongo)
3. Insert your cleaned data !

Redis is perfect for that, you can use Memcached or Mysql Memory, according your needs

Comment: OP is not asking for redis.

Comment: I use Redis to store the queue, or to store the already inserted URL.